# Capitalizing every other word in a string

Tags: java

I've been trying to use an array but it just seems to return the original String.

```
public static String capitalizeEveryOtherWord(String x) {
    x = x.toLowerCase();
    x.trim();
    String[] words = x.split(" ");
    for(int c = 2; c < words.length; c += 2)
        words[c].toUpperCase();
    return Arrays.toString(words);
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

`toUpperCase()` and `trim()` return new strings instead of modifying existing ones. You need to assign those new strings to something.

```
public static String capitalizeEveryOtherWord(String x) {
    x = x.toLowerCase();
    x = x.trim();
    String[] words = x.split(" ");
    for (int c = 2; c < words.length; c += 2)
        words[c] = words[c].toUpperCase();
    return Arrays.toString(words);
}
```

Also, you probably meant to start at index 0 or 1 – the first or second element, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Minitech has correctly identified the problem IMHO, but I would use a different regex-based approach:

```
public static String capitalizeEveryOtherWord(String x) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(x);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^ *\\w|\\w* \\w+ \\w").matcher(x);
    while(matcher.find())
        result.setCharAt(matcher.end() - 1, Character.toUpperCase(x.charAt(matcher.end() - 1)));
    return result.toString();
}
```

(Tested and works).

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
public class answerForStackOverflow {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String examplestring = "iwouldreallyliketothankforallthehelponstackoverflow";
    String output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < examplestring.length(); i++) {
        char c = examplestring.charAt(i);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            output += examplestring.substring(i, i + 1).toUpperCase();
        } else {
            output += examplestring.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```